# Finding the reciprocals using trigonometric functions and their inverses

Tags: functions, trigonometry, inverse

If $x\neq0$, how to find the reciprocal of $x$ only by using trigonometric functions and inverse trigonometric functions?

I have found only one answer, which is;
$\tan (\cos ^{-1}(\sin(\tan^{-1}(x))))=\frac{1}{x}$.

Is there any other answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**

Recall that

- for $x>0$

$$\arctan x = \frac{\pi}2-\arctan \frac1x$$

- for $x<0$

$$\arctan x = -\frac{\pi}2-\arctan \frac1x$$

Answer (score 1):

What about $\cot(\arctan x)$?